# Filter Ip remote SFTP

Tags: java, sftp, scp, apache-mina

Currently, I'm implementing SFTP server which using ssh-core and apache mina-core.

I want to filter ip remote address. I implemented class CustomFilterAdapter extends IoFilterAdapter and I check if Ip remote is not in range of whitelist, i will not create session

```
public void sessionCreated(NextFilter nextFilter, IoSession session) throws Exception
{
    log.debug(String.format("Start check access for ip %s.", ((InetSocketAddress)session.getRemoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress()));
    try
    {
        isAllowAccess(session);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.error("Access dinied.  " + ex.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    super.sessionCreated(nextFilter, session);
}
```

However, It's not work. It's not run my code.
What steps i was missed or I implemented wrong filter.

Comment: Can you also show the code that adds your `CustomFilterAdapter ` to the filterchain ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was missed add to FilterChain.